# Run a SQL statement in excel taking data as input from excel sheet itself

Tags: excel, oracle, sql-insert

i want to run a sql script in excel or in SQL developer. the problem is that I want the script to take input data from excel. example:

SQL script: `select * from ABC where data in (**NEED NUMBERS FROM EXCEL HERE!!!**)`

FORMAT OF NUMBERS IN EXCEL:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      123454         |         ,        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      123423         |         ,        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      653454         |         ,        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

is there any way to reference this data from excel to SQL?
The numbers that I have in excel sheet is around 80000+ rows.
running in toad not allowing me to use more that 999 number in 1 go.

Comment: What's SQL developer? Is that the one used to connect to Oracle DB? Seems like pythonic ways would be suitable.Btw, can you fix the sample data format?

Comment: i edited my post.

Comment: and toad just read now, your DB should be Oracle.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes db is oracle.  I have very simple query. Which takes data like (123, 367,626,887.......)

Comment: It is simple enough (if you have the permissions) in SQL:Developer  to create a table (Tables->Import Data) from that 1 column in Excel and then use JOIN..

Answer (score 0):

If possible, can you import this data from the excel sheet into an SQL table and then run the query on it?

SQL Developer provides functionality to import data from an excel sheet into a DB table.
This link can guide you to do the same.

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/

Not sure whether Toad supports this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **read_excel** function of **pandas** software library of **python** to inser the numbers in the first column of your excel sheet :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\\excel\\myExcelSheet.xls')

import cx_Oracle
con=cx_Oracle.connect('uname/pwd@host:port/service_name')
cur=con.cursor()

sql = 'insert into abc(data) values(:hd1)'

df_list = df.values.tolist()

for i, r in df.iterrows():
        cur.execute(sql,(df_list[i][0],))

con.commit()
con.close()
```